# vb .net Insertar datos en ms Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Creando una aplicacion en Visual Studio, hasta ahora eh logrado hacer el login con usuario y contraseña pero mi problema ahora es dar de alta nuevos usuarios dede la misma aplicacion.

Intente esto:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class RegistroUsuarios
    Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
        Try
            Dim Mycn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\ifsapp.mdb;")
            Mycn.Open()
            Dim SQLstr = "INSERT INTO RegistroUsuarios  VALUES('" & txtNombre.Text & "','" & txtApPa.Text & "','" & txtApMa.Text & "', '" & txtUsuario.Text & "', '" & txtContra.Text & "', '" & boxTipoUsuario.Text & "', '" & txtCorreo.Text & "', '" & timeNac.Text & "')"
            Dim Command As New OleDbCommand
            Command = New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, Mycn)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Esto me da este error:

> El número de consulta de campos de destino son diferentes

La tabla RegistroUsuarios tiene 9 campos, el campo que no esta incluido en el INSERT es "ID" que es de autoincremento

Actualice el código, ahora esta así

```
Dim Mycn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\ifsapp.mdb;")
            Mycn.Open()

    Dim SQLstr = "INSERT INTO RegistroUsuarios (Nombre, FechaNacimiento, Tipo, Usuario, Clave, Correo) VALUES('" & txtNombre.Text & "','" & timeNac.Text & "', '" & boxTipoUsuario.Text & "','" & txtUsuario.Text & "', '" & txtContra.Text & "',  '" & txtCorreo.Text & "')"
    Dim Command As New OleDbCommand
    Command = New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, Mycn)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Ahora tengo este mensaje:

> La operación debe usar una consulta actualizable

Comment: Mas alla que no es recomendable generar un query asi (mejor mandarle parametros, en access los parametros se marcan con ?), podrias hacer un msgbox.show de SQLstr y verificar como queda la cadena? y si podes, copiala en access a ver que te dice.

Comment: Solo especificas el nombre de la tabla donde quieres insertar, pero no especificas en qué campos. De la manera que tú lo estás usando, solamente es válido siempre y cuando vayas a insertar información en todos los campos de tu tabla. Como no es el caso, tienes que especificar en qué campos quieres insertar los valores. Algo tipo `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)` debería funcionarte.[SQL INSERT INTO Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Como es eso de mandarle parámetros?

Comment: Puedes ponernos la definición de la tabla en la que intentas introducir los datos? puede ser que te esté dando problemas por los tipos de datos (si fecha de nacimiento es tipo DATE por ejemplo)